# Relation between Weierstrass $\wp$-functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, integer-lattices, elliptic-functions

> Let $\Lambda=[\lambda_1,\lambda_2]$ be a lattice with associated Weierstrass function $\wp$, and consider the Weierstrass function $\wp_2$ associated to the lattice $\Lambda_2=[\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda_1,\lambda_2]$. Prove the identities $$\wp_2(z)=\wp(z)+\wp(z+\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda_1)-\wp(\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda_1)$$

Recall that $\wp(z)=\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{0\neq \omega \in \Lambda}\left( \dfrac{1}{(z-\omega)^2}-\dfrac{1}{\omega^2}\right)$

Every $\omega \in \Lambda$ has the form $\omega=n_\omega \lambda_1 + m_\omega \lambda_2$. Let $\omega_2 \in \Lambda_2$ we have $\omega_2=\omega-\tfrac{1}{2}n_\omega\lambda_1$. Therefore

$$\wp_2(z)=\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{0\neq \omega \in \Lambda}\left( \dfrac{1}{(z-\omega+\tfrac{1}{2}n_\omega\lambda_1)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(\omega-\tfrac{1}{2}n_\omega\lambda_1)^2}\right)$$
$$\wp(\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda_1)=\dfrac{4}{\lambda_1^2}+\sum_{0 \neq \omega \in \Lambda}\left(\dfrac{1}{(\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda_1-\omega)^2}-\dfrac{1}{\omega^2}\right)$$
$$\wp(z+\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda_1)=\dfrac{1}{(z+\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda_1)^2}+\sum_{0 \neq \omega \in \Lambda} \left( \dfrac{1}{(z-\omega+\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda_1)^2}- \dfrac{1}{\omega^2}\right)$$

I'm stuck here because I don't know how to deal with these infinite sum.

Comment: The lattice $\,\Lambda_2\,$ includes **all** of the points in lattice $\,\Lambda\,$ **and** their shifted copies $\,\omega\mapsto\omega+\lambda_1/2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a lattice $\,\Lambda,\,$ the Weierstrass $\wp$ function is characterized by being a
meromorphic doubly periodic function with period
lattice $\,\Lambda\,$ whose only poles are at points in $\,\Lambda,\,$
 and whose Laurent series at the origin is
$\,\wp (z) = z^{-2} + O(z^2)$. In your first equation, note
that the right side satisfies the poles and Laurent series
properties for the lattice $\,\Lambda_2.$

The Wikipedia article [Weierstrass elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) states

> Further development of the theory of elliptic functions shows that Weierstrass's function is determined up to addition of a constant and multiplication by a non-zero constant by the position and type of the poles alone, amongst all meromorphic functions with the given period lattice.

Comment: could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: @Desunkid What detail is missing? What needs explaining?

Comment: Thanks. Your hint is helpful and I find the answer already